# Relational algebra ONLY & EVERYWHERE

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Here is a simple database

```
/* Delete the tables if they already exist */
drop table if exists Person;
drop table if exists Frequents;
drop table if exists Eats;
drop table if exists Serves;

/* Create the schema for our tables */
create table Person(name text, age int, gender text);
create table Frequents(name text, pizzeria text);
create table Eats(name text, pizza text);
create table Serves(pizzeria text, pizza text, price decimal);

/* Populate the tables with our data */
insert into Person values('Amy', 16, 'female');
insert into Person values('Ben', 21, 'male');
insert into Person values('Cal', 33, 'male');
insert into Person values('Dan', 13, 'male');
insert into Person values('Eli', 45, 'male');
insert into Person values('Fay', 21, 'female');
insert into Person values('Gus', 24, 'male');
insert into Person values('Hil', 30, 'female');
insert into Person values('Ian', 18, 'male');

insert into Frequents values('Amy', 'Pizza Hut');
insert into Frequents values('Ben', 'Pizza Hut');
insert into Frequents values('Ben', 'Chicago Pizza');
insert into Frequents values('Cal', 'Straw Hat');
insert into Frequents values('Cal', 'New York Pizza');
insert into Frequents values('Dan', 'Straw Hat');
insert into Frequents values('Dan', 'New York Pizza');
insert into Frequents values('Eli', 'Straw Hat');
insert into Frequents values('Eli', 'Chicago Pizza');
insert into Frequents values('Fay', 'Dominos');
insert into Frequents values('Fay', 'Little Caesars');
insert into Frequents values('Gus', 'Chicago Pizza');
insert into Frequents values('Gus', 'Pizza Hut');
insert into Frequents values('Hil', 'Dominos');
insert into Frequents values('Hil', 'Straw Hat');
insert into Frequents values('Hil', 'Pizza Hut');
insert into Frequents values('Ian', 'New York Pizza');
insert into Frequents values('Ian', 'Straw Hat');
insert into Frequents values('Ian', 'Dominos');

insert into Eats values('Amy', 'pepperoni');
insert into Eats values('Amy', 'mushroom');
insert into Eats values('Ben', 'pepperoni');
insert into Eats values('Ben', 'cheese');
insert into Eats values('Cal', 'supreme');
insert into Eats values('Dan', 'pepperoni');
insert into Eats values('Dan', 'cheese');
insert into Eats values('Dan', 'sausage');
insert into Eats values('Dan', 'supreme');
insert into Eats values('Dan', 'mushroom');
insert into Eats values('Eli', 'supreme');
insert into Eats values('Eli', 'cheese');
insert into Eats values('Fay', 'mushroom');
insert into Eats values('Gus', 'mushroom');
insert into Eats values('Gus', 'supreme');
insert into Eats values('Gus', 'cheese');
insert into Eats values('Hil', 'supreme');
insert into Eats values('Hil', 'cheese');
insert into Eats values('Ian', 'supreme');
insert into Eats values('Ian', 'pepperoni');

insert into Serves values('Pizza Hut', 'pepperoni', 12);
insert into Serves values('Pizza Hut', 'sausage', 12);
insert into Serves values('Pizza Hut', 'cheese', 9);
insert into Serves values('Pizza Hut', 'supreme', 12);
insert into Serves values('Little Caesars', 'pepperoni', 9.75);
insert into Serves values('Little Caesars', 'sausage', 9.5);
insert into Serves values('Little Caesars', 'cheese', 7);
insert into Serves values('Little Caesars', 'mushroom', 9.25);
insert into Serves values('Dominos', 'cheese', 9.75);
insert into Serves values('Dominos', 'mushroom', 11);
insert into Serves values('Straw Hat', 'pepperoni', 8);
insert into Serves values('Straw Hat', 'cheese', 9.25);
insert into Serves values('Straw Hat', 'sausage', 9.75);
insert into Serves values('New York Pizza', 'pepperoni', 8);
insert into Serves values('New York Pizza', 'cheese', 7);
insert into Serves values('New York Pizza', 'supreme', 8.5);
insert into Serves values('Chicago Pizza', 'cheese', 7.75);
insert into Serves values('Chicago Pizza', 'supreme', 8.5);
```

The question is 'Find all pizzas that are eaten only by people younger than 24, or that cost less than $10 everywhere they're served'.The problem comes here :

```
\project_{pizza} ( Eats \join \select_{age < 24 } Person)
```

I write this way but there's one thing lacking.It says only by people younger than 24.Similarly for the second 'everywhere served' problem still exists.How can I limit that??

Comment: If you feel like you must post your homework here, at least make some effort to write down the database scheme instead of just posting a link. This looks just too lazy.

Comment: @fab Sorry.I thought it would be long and ugly.I wrote it now.Thank you.

Comment: And what have you tried. PS you have been taught how terrible this schema is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT pizza AS oldest_age
FROM Person
JOIN Eats ON Eats.name = Person.name
GROUP BY pizza
HAVING MAX( age ) <24

UNION ALL

SELECT pizza AS highest_price
FROM Serves
GROUP BY pizza
HAVING MAX( price ) <10;
```